# Clock on Website Alignment Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, alignment

I am a novice at CSS/JavaScript, I have ran into an issue where I need the JavaScript Clock at the top of the page to be aligned to center and on ONE line instead of two. 
Example:
Logged in at:Wed Jul 05 2017 16:25:08 GMT-0400 (EDT) Current Time:16:32:06

The code that I have is as follows:

```
  function currentTime() 
  {
     var today   = new Date();
     var hour    = today.getHours();
     var minutes = today.getMinutes();
     var sec     = today.getSeconds();

     minutes = checkTime(minutes);
     sec     = checkTime(sec);

     document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "Current Time : "+hour+":"+minutes+":"+sec;

     var t = setTimeout(function(){currentTime()},500);

  }


  function checkTime(i) 
  {
     if (i<10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
     return i;
  }


  /*
  getDate()           Returns the day of the month (from 1-31)
  getDay()            Returns the day of the week (from 0-6)
  getFullYear()   Returns the year (four digits)
  getHours()      Returns the hour (from 0-23)
  getMilliseconds()   Returns the milliseconds (from 0-999)
  getMinutes()    Returns the minutes (from 0-59)
  getMonth()      Returns the month (from 0-11)
  getSeconds()    Returns the seconds (from 0-59)
  getTime()           Returns the number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970
  getTimezoneOffset() Returns the time difference between UTC time and local time, in minutes
  getUTCDate()    Returns the day of the month, according to universal time (from 1-31)
  getUTCDay()     Returns the day of the week, according to universal time (from 0-6)
  getUTCFullYear()    Returns the year, according to universal time (four digits)
  getUTCHours()   Returns the hour, according to universal time (from 0-23)
  getUTCMilliseconds()Returns the milliseconds, according to universal time (from 0-999)
  getUTCMinutes()     Returns the minutes, according to universal time (from 0-59)
  getUTCMonth()   Returns the month, according to universal time (from 0-11)
  getUTCSeconds()     Returns the seconds, according to universal time (from 0-59)
  getYear()           Deprecated. Use the getFullYear() method instead
  parse()             Parses a date string and returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970

  setDate()           Sets the day of the month of a date object
  setFullYear()   Sets the year (four digits) of a date object
  setHours()      Sets the hour of a date object
  setMilliseconds()   Sets the milliseconds of a date object
  setMinutes()    Set the minutes of a date object
  setMonth()      Sets the month of a date object
  setSeconds()    Sets the seconds of a date object
  setTime()           Sets a date to a specified number of milliseconds after/before January 1, 1970
  setUTCDate()    Sets the day of the month of a date object, according to universal time
  setUTCFullYear()    Sets the year of a date object, according to universal time (four digits)
  setUTCHours()   Sets the hour of a date object, according to universal time
  setUTCMilliseconds()Sets the milliseconds of a date object, according to universal time
  setUTCMinutes()     Set the minutes of a date object, according to universal time
  setUTCMonth()   Sets the month of a date object, according to universal time
  setUTCSeconds()     Set the seconds of a date object, according to universal time
  setYear()           Deprecated. Use the setFullYear() method instead
  toDateString()      Converts the date portion of a Date object into a readable string
  toGMTString()   Deprecated. Use the toUTCString() method instead
  toISOString()   Returns the date as a string, using the ISO standard
  toJSON()            Returns the date as a string, formatted as a JSON date
  toLocaleDateString()Returns the date portion of a Date object as a string, using locale conventions
  toLocaleTimeString()Returns the time portion of a Date object as a string, using locale conventions
  toLocaleString()    Converts a Date object to a string, using locale conventions
  toString()      Converts a Date object to a string
  toTimeString()      Converts the time portion of a Date object to a string
  toUTCString()   Converts a Date object to a string, according to universal time
  UTC()           Returns the number of milliseconds in a date since midnight of 
                          January 1, 1970, according to UTC time
  valueOf()           Returns the primitive value of a Date object 
  */
```

```
  loggedInTime();

  var temp1;

  function loggedInTime( temp )
  {
     var tiempo = new Date();  
     var temp2 =  "Logged in at &nbsp;: " + tiempo;
     temp1 = temp2;
     document.write( temp2 );
  }


  //document.write( " " + "I am next " + temp1 ); 

  currentTime();
```

Comment: Don't use document.write.

Comment: This will have to do with your html and css.  Please edit your question to include them.